# Functional equation $f(x+y)\leq yf(x)+f(f(x)).$

Tags: functional-equations

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that

$$f(x+y)\leq yf(x)+f(f(x)).$$

What can be the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$

Comment: Most old IMO problems have well documented solutions online, [here](https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2011SL.pdf) for instance.  This problem is $A6$.

Comment: Please correct your title : An inequality is not an equation !